# Is "the large number of genes" grammatically wrong or is it a glitch from Grammarly?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Grammarly asks me to change the "this process is infeasible due to the computational cost of the optimization process and **the** large number of genes. " sentence to "this process is infeasible due to the computational cost of the optimization process and **a** large number of genes. " and I don't understand why. Is it something wrong with my sentence?

Comment: It's something wrong with Grammarly.. Whether you use "a" or "the" depends on the context. What is it?

Comment: "The" for sure. I was wondering maybe I am in the wrong. I am trying to say that the number of genes in our data is large, therefore the process is infeasible.

Comment: That's a correct use of "the". A correct use of "a" would go like this: If the data set contains a large number of genes, the process becomes infeasible. "The" is definite, and "a" is indefinite.

Comment: Or something like "this process is infeasible due to a large number of genes being present"